# Can I delete and recreate a list (from template) with the same ID as the list before?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, id, delete-list

I have to show a report daily, which was pulled out of an excel file (importExcel).
This works so far. To reset the ID, I daily delete the list and recreate it from a template which I created. It works fine too.

The problem is, that I would like to have a page with the Webpart, showing the list. But I know that each creation of the list will produce a new id and therefore the Webpart is useless.

My question is, if there is a possibility to retain the ID and use it again and again when creating the list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, what is your SharePoint version?

Comment: If you want to show data, then upload excel in document library and show data from excel only.  In sharepoint online you get file viewer webpart to show data from file.

Comment: Our SharePoint version is 2013

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, as you create a new list daily, there is no OOB approach to make the list web part to recognize the new list. You may need to edit the list web part to show the new list you create every day.

Comment: ….except there is possibility to use the same list ID for each days new list. An edit of the Webpart itself is not an option because we have not that much knowhow AND we try to use SharePoint as much as possible OOB